# Manual culture conversion in string replace

Tags: c#

Sorry if very basic question, but somehow I don't find a simple solution.

I would like to manually convert dots and commas in a string.

**Requirement**

every string should contain only one comma before the last 3 chars
and each string can contain one dot for each 3 chars

**XXX.XXX.XXX,XXX**

How can I convert input to output of the following:

```
 1. Input= 102.123.444,696  output = no change
 2. Input= 102,123,444.666  output = 102.123.444,696
 3. Input= 444.666          output = 444,666
 4. input= 123,444.666      output = 123.444,666
 5. input= 0.666            output = 0,666
 6. input= .666             output= 0,666
 7. input= ABC,CCC.DD       output= ABC.CCC,DD
 8. input= .abc             output= 0,abc
```

Comment: use the string.Replace method are you familiar with that..? it's very straight forward...

Comment: yes i'm, but how can i combine all these conditions in an efficient way or should i use if else

Comment: @MethodMan I wouldn't say it's *very* straight forward, once you replace one you can no longer replace the other (he wants to replace commas with periods AND vice-versa). Would need to find indices for each replacement, then go through and do each replace manually. Generically you wouldn't even use string.Replace, though you could find the indices for one replacement, then string.Replace the other replacement, then go back to the saved indices and modify those..

Comment: @Maro: You seem to be assuming that each number will definitely have 3 decimal places, is that right? Is there any possibility that "444.666" actually means 444.666,000 instead of 444,666?

Comment: what are the requirements: Why is the first one staying the same but the others are being replaced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should parse the number as double with the origin culture and `ToString` it back with the other culture.

```
double number = double.Parse("102.123.444,696", new CultureInfo("culturecode"));
string output = number.ToString("N", new CultureInfo("otherculturecode");
```

Where you should replace the "culturecode" with the code of origin culture ("en-US" for example) and "otherculturecode" with the destination culture code.

Comment: A good start. This doesn't address the first input/output pair in the question, though.

Comment: I need to do this without cultureInfo

Comment: @Maro why the requirement of not using cultureinfo? It's pretty much mandatory when parsing strings.

Comment: because the input can be number can be alphabet ...etc will update my question

Comment: Well then that's a completely different question. You'll probably have to do with tryparse and some if.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will find the solution you are looking for here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This code makes a ton of assumptions and relies on ascii characters, i.e., this won't work with weird Unicode commas or periods, if they even exist. It assumes the strings are already in a valid format before hand and simply changes commas to periods and vice versa using the condition that if the first separator found when scanning right->left is a comma then no changes necessary, but if it's a period then swap all commas with periods and vice versa. I didn't handle adding the leading 0 to the cases that are only decimal places. I think it would be wise to use this code only for the alphabet cases and to use the culture info answers when you have actual numbers.

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>() { "102.123.444,696", "102,123,444.666",
            "444.666", "123,444.666", "0.666", ".666", "ABC,CCC.DD", ".abc" };
List<string> outputStrings = new List<string>();

foreach (var s in strings)
{
    // Scan from right. If find ',' first, no changes, otherwise replace everything found
    bool foundPeriod = false;
    bool foundComma = false;
    bool foundCommaFirst = false;
    string outputString = string.Empty;
    foreach (var character in s.Reverse())
    {
        if (character == '.')
        {
            foundPeriod = true;
        }

        if (character == ',')
        {
            foundComma = true;
        }

        if (!foundComma && foundPeriod)
        {
            foundCommaFirst = true;
        }

        if (foundCommaFirst)
        {
            // This means we need to replace everything with the opposite
            // Create the string backwards then reverse it later to make life easier
            if (character == ',')
            {
                outputString += ".";
            }
            else if (character == '.')
            {
                outputString += ",";
            }
            else
            {
                outputString += character;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            outputString += character;
        }
    }

    // Reverse it
    var charArray = outputString.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(charArray);
    outputString = new string(charArray);

    outputStrings.Add(outputString);
}
```

Comment: Appending to a string in a loop like this has `O(n²)` complexity. (In other words, performance becomes obscenely bad as the number of characters in the string increases.) Use a [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution. It makes a few assumptions based on the samples you gave, but in the absence of more complete requirements it's probably about the best you can get:

```
public string UseCommasForDecimals(string input)
{
    string[] split = input.Split(',', '.');
    var fraction = split.Last();
    var wholeNumber = string.Join(".", split.Take(split.Length - 1));
    if (wholeNumber.Length == 0)
    {
        wholeNumber = "0";
    }
    return wholeNumber + "," + fraction;
}
```